# Получение ВСЕХ релизов на гитхабе

Tags: github, github-api

С помощью github api получаю список релизов.
В ответ сервер выдаёт список релизов, но не всех.
Инфу искал [тут](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases)

Также в документации указано вот это:
Status: 200 OK
Link: https://api.github.com/resource?page=2; rel="next",
https://api.github.com/resource?page=5; rel="last"
Как это использовать.
Надеюсь, я понятно объяснил

Comment: Документацию обновили: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-releases

Comment: Каких именно релизов не хватает в ответе? В справке указано, что не возвращаются только теги несвязанные с релизом